# Copy files from the find function into a new folder without overwriting any files Terminal

Tags: terminal, copy, find, duplicates, rename

I want to copy all files(which all have the same name) from all Subfolders to a new folder:

```
$cd /My/Folder

$find /Users/My/Other/Folder -name "result.xml" -exec cp '{}' ./ \;
```

Because all files have the same name it is overwriting itself the whole time. I would like it to always create a new name for every file.
The new files should be called result.xml, result1.xml, result2.xml...